# Android upload to Firebase Bucket with SchedulerAPI

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, scheduler

Background:

I am using Firebase for my Android App Development This app require every user upload an object from their phone to the bucket/ Firebase Storage once a day. So, I want to make the process of "object upload" as a background service with JobSchedulerAPI.
I have copied source code from Firebase and a youtube video related to Job Scheduler. But when I clicked the button, the app stopped immediately.

MainActivity.Java

```
package com.scheduleupload;

import android.app.job.JobInfo;
import android.app.job.JobScheduler;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        final ComponentName mComponentName = new ComponentName(this, Scheduler.class);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                JobInfo info = new JobInfo.Builder(123, mComponentName)
                        .setPeriodic(15 * 60 * 1000)
                        .build();

                JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
                int resultCode = scheduler.schedule(info);
                if (resultCode == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Job scheduled");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Job scheduling failed");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Scheduler.Java

```
package com.scheduleupload;

import android.app.job.JobParameters;
import android.app.job.JobService;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

public class Scheduler extends JobService {
    private static final String TAG = "ExampleJobService";
    private boolean jobCancelled =false;

    private StorageReference mStorage;
    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    String myUri = "content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D1%3Bdoc%3D693";
    final Uri uri = Uri.parse(myUri);
    StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("Photos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Job Started");
        doBackgroundWork(params);
        return true;
    }

    private void doBackgroundWork(JobParameters params) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                filepath.putFile(uri);
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thx a lot for spending such a long while to read my question

crash log:

```
05-07 21:53:52.775 6261-6261/com.scheduleupload E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.scheduleupload, PID: 6261
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such service ComponentInfo{com.scheduleupload/com.scheduleupload.Scheduler}
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2008)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1950)
        at android.app.job.IJobScheduler$Stub$Proxy.schedule(IJobScheduler.java:180)
        at android.app.JobSchedulerImpl.schedule(JobSchedulerImpl.java:44)
        at com.scheduleupload.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:35)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: What is crash log?

Answer (score 0):

Have found solution, it is because the Scheduler can't access to some of the storage. Simply change to file location to somewhere it is accessible by Job Scheduler can solve the problem

Comment: I've been searching for something like this for days. Does this code work fine or show error?